# ideal chain replacement for Redline monocog 29er

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, single-speed

I have a Redline Monocog 29er and I'm replacing the drive train.  The bike's purpose is to be abused off-road.  For the new chain, I'm debating between the SRAM PC-1 Single-Speed Chain  ($6.39)  and the KMC Z610HX ($15.76)  I'm wondering what, if anything, the more expensive KMC chain would offer?  Would it wear longer?  Is it stronger?  Will the cheaper one snap when I'm standing up and cranking hard?

Some forum posters recommend just using an old worn one off of a geared bike??  Is that advisable?

Comment: Well, you might not have a choice one way or the other -- the PC-1 is a 1/8" chain, Z610HX is a 3/32" chain. What width are you running on the bike now?

Answer (score 1):

I think the ideal chain replacement would be the Sram PC-1.  I use this on my single speed mountain bike and stand up and crank on it with no issues what so ever.  The installation is very straight forward and the master link is very easy to use.  I would definitely not recommend an old multi-speed chain for this application mainly because the PC-1 is so affordable and effective.  The one issue that I do have with the PC-1 is that the master link is a bit wide and it does rub a bit on the bashguard that is installed on my Sram crankset, but it does not affect performance in any way.

Comment: If it is being 'abused' it would make sense to buy cheap and buy often. He's not eating big miles on a road bike. Keep it reasonably clean and change every 4-6 months and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

KMC Z33 from Google search. Check manufacture specs http://www.jensonusa.com/Redline-Monocog-Bike-2014

$11 [https://www.amazon.com/KMC-Chain-Speed-Nickel-Plated/dp/B000AYFRUE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AYFRUE)
Your chain is 1/2" x 3/32

Comment: For the 2014 Monocog, this is right. But OP didn't say what year bike he had.

Comment: That is why I said check manufacturer specs. I'm sure any 1/2" x 3/32 chain would work.